# How to implement the "selectpicker" class for all the select element in website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I have a website, backend using Django, frontend using normal HTML5.

I want to change all the default selection box to the class: "selectpicker" once in some place so it could be implemented in all the selection box in the websites.

How could I do that in one place?

I have tried:

base.html

```
<style>
select {
class="selectpicker";
}
</style>
    ...
```

app.html

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
<style>
select {
class="selectpicker";
}
</style>
```

But failed to do so.

I want this kind of solution, better only make change in base.html to change all the selection box in the websites as I have tons of HTML in my website.

Comment: Can't understand your question clearly, if you're trying to add `selectpicker` class to `select` element, using scss you can add `@extend .selectpicker;` to `select`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want. But where should I add @extend .selectpicker;?

Comment: to the `select` element, works only with scss/sass

Comment: selectpicker is a bootstrap class for a beautiful selection box